# HTML is not showing in firefox before JS is loaded

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm just starting to learn the code, going through the courses.

I've made the react app, and have a basic HTML template to show up before the bundled.js is loading (for slow connection)

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Public+Sans:300,400,400i,700,700i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="..." crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/js/all.js" integrity="..." crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="app">
  <header class="header-bar bg-primary mb-3">
    <div class="container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3">
      <h4 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal"><a class="text-white" href="/">ComplexApp</a></h4>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="py-5 my-5 text-center">
    <div class="dots-loading">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="border-top text-center small text-muted py-3">
    <p>
      <a class="mx-1" href="/">Home</a>
      <!-- -->|
      <!-- -->
      <a class="mx-1" href="/about-us">About Us</a>
      <!-- -->|<a class="mx-1" href="/terms">Terms</a>
    </p>
    <p class="m-0">
      Copyright © 2020
      <!-- -->
      <a href="/" class="text-muted">ComplexApp</a>. All rights reserved.
    </p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

In Chrome, it loads nicely:
[image: Chrome screenshot]

But for some reason in Firefox, the page is blank until the js is fully loaded.

Network tab shows that CSS and fonts are loading all the time in parallel with js

[image: Firefox network screenshot]

What might be the problem? is it some Firefox-specific stuff? Can it be fixed somehow?

Comment: Can you update the snippet with relevant CSS and Script

Comment: Perhaps a stackblitz

Comment: well, css is 600 lines written not by me, and js is bundled.js monstrosity by webpack. both are too long to insert here

Comment: Ok good luck ... we really like [mcve]

Comment: I don't really know how to reproduce it without actual 1MB+ js file...

Comment: Ok, never mind.  -